# Instantiation of a generic module in Verilog

Tags: generics, parameter-passing, verilog

I'm trying to figure out how can I instantiate a generic module using the generate function while overriding two of it's paramateres.

I have a generic arbiter that I should send to it two parameters (**HEIGHT**  and **SIZE**). these two parameters are also defined as parameters in the "top" module

Here is how I instantiate  the PRRA module (inner module) in the top hierarchy.

```
genvar i;
generate for(i=0 ; i<M ; i=i+1)
begin
    PRRA arbiter (
        .clk(clk),
        .reset(reset),
        .request(request[i]),
        .grant(grant[i])
        );
end
endgenerate
```

using defparam didn't work. Apparently I'm using it wrong.

I tried using it before/after/inside the generate but it did not pass :/

Can anyone help please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not clear how you have tried passing parameters to the lower module, as supplied code example does not reference HEIGHT or SIZE, but this is how you would pass parameters:

```
PRRA #(
    .HEIGHT  ( HEIGHT_from_top )
    .SIZE    ( SIZE_from_top   )
) arbiter (
    .clk     (clk       ),
    .reset   (reset     ),
    .request (request[i]),
    .grant   (grant[i]  )
);
```

Where you have :

```
module PRRA #(
  parameter HEIGHT = -1,
  parameter SIZE   = -1
)(
 //inputs ...
 //outputs ...
);
//...
endmodule
```